# vb.net code convert in python. .net for loop to python for loop

Tags: python, vb.net, for-loop

I want to convert vb.net code(for loop) to python code(for loop).
Is there any way to covert this code in python?

```
For ea As Double = -45 * 0.01745 To +45 * 0.01745 Step 5 * 0.01745
     Console.WriteLine(ea)
Next
```

Output like :-

```
-0.78525
-0.698
-0.61075
-0.5235
-0.43625
-0.349
-0.26175
-0.1745
-0.0872499999999999
1.11022302462516E-16
0.0872500000000001
0.1745
0.26175
0.349
0.43625
0.5235
0.61075
0.698
```

Demo link:- https://dotnetfiddle.net/B10ox9

I don't how can I convert this code in python.

Thank you advance

Comment: be careful with these floating point operations and loops that do comparisons...might end up with differing results between languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using while loop:

**Ex.**

```
start = -45 * 0.01745
end =  45 * 0.01745
step = 5 * 0.01745

while start <= end:
    print(start)
    start += step
```

**O/P:**

```
-0.78525
-0.698
-0.6107499999999999
-0.5234999999999999
-0.43624999999999986
-0.34899999999999987
-0.26174999999999987
-0.17449999999999988
-0.08724999999999988
1.1102230246251565e-16
0.0872500000000001
0.1745000000000001
0.2617500000000001
0.3490000000000001
0.4362500000000001
0.5235000000000001
0.6107500000000001
0.6980000000000002
```